# How do i implement intellisense for my language in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I mention that i am designing a language. The plan was always to not implement it but to design it but i am considering implementing it if i think i could do it in a reasonable amount of time.

How would i have my language use intellisense in visual studios? BooLangStudio has it http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/boo-in-visual-studio.html, http://www.codeplex.com/BooLangStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb507746.aspx#extensibility) is a good place to look for Visual Studio Extensibility.

Also, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx). But, the first link has a video specific to adding Intellisense to your language service.

Answer (score 25):

It all depends on how much time you want to spend on it. I have about 2,000 hours of work in my Visual Studio IntelliSense projects resulting in exactly one mostly-complete language service. That said, it's not your "average" IntelliSense extension to Visual Studio - see the [feature set for more info](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:nFringe:Features).

Here are some good resources to look at. I have a tendency to write with an assumption that users are already familiar with both the Visual Studio Extensibility basics and parsing with ANTLR. If you aren't, you should probably start at [www.antlr.org](http://www.antlr.org) and with my "ANTLR port" of one of the [simple Visual Studio language service tutorials](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2008/10/21/).

Here are some posts showing how serious I am about the subject. :D

- [How does code completion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220099/how-does-code-completion-work/1220226#1220226)
- Smart code-completion [original](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2008/10/20/) and [revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229592/intellisense-rules-for-get-best-match-during-member-selection). Clearly I take the latter more seriously than other people (voted down and voted to close?!), but I believe doing so just gives my users a better product. :)
- High-speed incremental lexing for syntax highlighting [original (under IScanner-friendly lexers)](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2008/10/21/), [cleaned up (significantly - vastly preferable to the original)](http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2009-April/034053.html), and made [yet again 6x faster in 1/4 the memory](http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-dev/2009-May/002305.html).
- Little things like [sane commenting/uncommenting](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2008/10/19/) and [brace matching](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2009/03/27/) do make a difference. On a side note, once you use one that's well-behaved, the others (including the ones for some Microsoft languages in Visual Studio) are rather annoying.
- If you can, read all the IntelliSense-related posts on my blog.
- Smart indent is a PITA (I mean really smart, e.g. the C# language service in VS2008). I have a love/hate relationship with it. I'm annoyed now because writing this bullet made me think about it. Argh. My insight here makes me a bit forgiving of them breaking it for VS2010 Beta 1, but it doesn't keep me from missing its awesomeness.

PS: I can now build a syntax highlighter for a new language commenting/uncommenting in 1 day. In the same day I'm ofter able to get the type & member bars in as well.

Comment: if you ever feel like joining a OSS project integrating a new language into VS then take a look at Marvin fulloo.info/Examples/Marvin or github.com/runefs/Marvin

Comment: @280Z28, I've been also hacking with Visual Studio extensibility. The question I haven't been able to answer is though: what is the "RIGHT" way to implement fully blown language service, as VS2012/VS2010 has? Right now I have been using MEF to implement everything(IWpfTextViewCreationListener, IClassifier, IQuickInfoSource, ISignatureHelpSource, ICompletionSource) etc.. It seems to be working, but I wonder if implementing ILanguageService is better approach?

Answer (score 0):

As of 4-4-2017: This article seems to give all of the basics for creating a language extension, which includes highlighting words and providing intellisense (code completion).

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server