# Is it possible to add items to Visual Studio IntelliSense™ drop-down?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've found examples of how to implement full IntelliSense™ providers for specific file-types in VS2010, like for Ruby or Python or whatever. What I want to do is hook into the existing IntelliSense™ for C# or VB.NET and add additional items into the list that is already generated by Visual Studio. (Basically, I want to inject database-driven items into the IntelliSense™ for Simple.Data objects.)

Is this actually possible, and if so, how do I go about it?

Comment: Mark, did it turn out to be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

[XML Editor IntelliSense Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255811.aspx) and where to put the new schema for intellisense: [Schema Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx)

To answer the comment:

I just found this on stackoverflow: 
[How do i implement intellisense for my language in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250321/how-do-i-implement-intellisense-for-my-language-in-visual-studio)

Here is someone that implemented ADT support (android dev in Visual Studio). Maybe you can get some ideas from it:

[VS ADT](http://www.vsadt.com/blog/?currentPage=2)

Comment: That's just for XML, isn't it? I want to add things in C# or VB.NET files.