# How to add completion proposals to Visual Studio intellisense programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio extension that can contribute to existing completion proposals from visual studio. For example, when someone types a dot(.) after an object name the VS IntelliSense offers a list of completion proposals. How can I add my own list of completion proposals to that list?

Closest Question: The closest question I found is: [[Is it possible to add items to Visual Studio IntelliSense™ drop-down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910525/is-it-possible-to-add-items-to-visual-studio-intellisense%E2%84%A2-drop-down]). However, the question is quite old and with the introduction of VS2015, I am hoping that it is now possible.

Note: I take a look on the documentation of extending editor and language services and run the displaying signature help plugin(
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee334194.aspx).
But again, the new proposals I am adding are displaying in a different window, instead of integrating with the default list of proposals (see the following picture). Is it actually possible to turn off the built-in IntelliSense? 
[image]